# Viewing Xml as Html

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XML file and I am applying XSLT stylesheet on it + CSS. I can see all XSLT changes applied to XML file when reading XML file in browser. However when I try to inspect code it shows data in XML, but I want HTML code.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What are you using to "inspect" the code?

Answer (score 1):

When a browser does an XSL transformation it takes the input XML and the XSLT stylesheet that is linked to your XML document. Because the result of the transform is displayed directly in the browser, the **browser doesn't need to output a serialization of the result document.**

The result of the transformation is only a tree (a document model). Therefore you see only your original XML file when you try to inspect the result with "view source" because that is the real source document that the browser receives from the server.

Comment: okay, I guess my question wasn't correct and needs some clarification. I have problem with reading parameters from URL by xslt, I guessed it could be done by xml not transforming to HTML. However, it works on server, but when i read it localy it doesnt.

Comment: XSLT doesn't read parameters from URL. You have to do it on server side.